# Can a drywall ceiling toggle bolt hold up a 18.5lb chandelier?

Tags: drywall-anchor

I'm hanging a 18.5lb chandelier, there is already a metal box in the ceiling from an old ceiling fan installed by the previous homeowners, the box is attached to a ceiling joist as required, however, it's not centered above my dining room table, I want to add a swag hook a few feet away so my new chandelier can be centered, is a toggle bolt in ceiling drywall on a sloped ceiling strong enough to support the swag hook and 18.5lb chandelier?

Comment: I would never trust drywall/plaster for anything like that.  Move the table or add proper supports.

Comment: Wrong question. You could hang it that way and it wouldn't fall. The question is, what happens if there's some flooding in the drywall gets wet, or someone's changing a bulb and pulls down a bit on the fixture, or someone gets up from the table and bang their head really hard on it?  What's the combined effect of changing light bulbs and cleaning the fixture over many years? The answer to all those questions is, it might fall.

Answer (score 7):

The toggle bolt will probably hold up just fine with a 20 lb. weight, but I can't say the same for the drywall itself.

Even if the drywall seems to hold for a while, do not trust it by hanging a 20 pound weight over your loved ones' heads like this.

You will want to install something solid in the ceiling to attach to. A piece of blocking between ceiling joists, or a hanger designed for the job.

Comment: Or install it to a joist.